# SU retag request : driver to drivers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

**Updated:**  driver(180) to drivers(131)

Comment: No preference on my part and it seems that drivers is more liked.  I will update the request.

Comment: +1 for the edit, I'll edit my answer to fit.

Comment: good catch.  i've noticed those a couple of times but never got around to posting the request.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Good idea, we should move all the singular `driver` to the plural `drivers`.

Answer (score 1):

I've done the merge as requested.